# Showing $\mathbb{R} \setminus E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \notin E\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, open-map

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of all positive integers. In $(\mathbb{R}, d)$, show that $E = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not closed, but $F = E \cup \{0\}$ is closed.

A theorem in my notes say that: A subset $F$ of a metric space $(X, \rho)$ is called closed if its complement

$X \setminus   F = \{x \in X : x \notin F \}$

is open.

If I use this theorem to prove the question, then I need to show that $\mathbb{R} \setminus E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \notin E\}$ is open.

Since a subset U in a metric space $\{X, \rho\}$ is open if for every $x \in U$, there
exists $r > 0$ (depending on x and U) such that $B(x, r) ⊆ U$.

Now I am stuck, finding a way of showing there always exist a $r>0$ s.t. $B(x, r) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus E$ for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus E$.

Could someone enlighten me on how I would show this?

Edit: When I originally posted this question I mistakenly used / to denote the contrapositive. I have edited / as \, to clear to confusion of what I'm trying to say.

Any answers that show a full solution to the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please note that there is a fundamental difference between \ and /; the first being 'the complement of a set' and the latter being 'the quotient of the two sets.

Comment: You are supposed to prove that $E$ is **not** closed, which is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb R \setminus E$ is **not** open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now I am stuck, finding a way of showing there always exist a $r>0$ s.t. $B(x, r) \subseteq \mathbb{R} / E$ for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}/E$.*

You'll never succeed doing that for $x=0$!

**Now take care!!!** The contrary of not being closed is not to be open. So you can't apply the theorem you mention.

However, you can use [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition). I.e. that the complement of $E$ is not open. And for that $0$ is your friend!

Comment: I don't know how to show this using the contrapositive. Which is what I mean't but have messed up the notation. I should have used \

Comment: Now that we have got past the confusion with the notation, could you possibly edit your post with a poof of how to solve the problem. I would really appreciate it, as I'm new to topologies

Comment: @Okbko You have almost all the elements in may answer: (1) for $E$ use a proof by contraposition and (2) the fact that any open ball centered on $0$ will have a non-empty intersection with $E$. And to prove that $F$ is closed, prove that its complement is open (look at open balls centered on $x$, separating the cases $x <0$ and $x>0$).

Comment: I'm still confused, could you post a proof of (1). I'm not sure how you prove (1) via the contrapositive

Comment: @Okbko are you confusing "contrapositive" and "complement"? You messed up the notation for the *complement* set, which has nothing at all to do with taking the *contrapositive* of a logical statement, which is a proof technique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find such an $r$ for $\Bbb R\setminus F$, because $F$ is the closed set, **not** $E$, as you note.